# omdb api no results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the omdb api for a project at home if I search for a movie with no results it still shows the details (title, year, plot etc) and a broken image from my previous successful search.

I am trying to stop it showing anything if the movie isn't found. Is this possible?

I have very limited knowledge of Javascript and Json but have been trying various things for some time and can't work it out. Any help would be most appreciated.

Here's my code before I messed it up trying things:

```
var $Form = $('#omdbform'), $Container = $('#containera');
$Container.hide();
$Form.on('click', function(p_oEvent){
    var sUrl, sMovie, oData;
    p_oEvent.preventDefault();
sMovie = $Form.find('#moviename').val();
    sUrl = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + sMovie + ''
    $.ajax(sUrl, {
        complete: function(p_oXHR, p_sStatus){
            oData = $.parseJSON(p_oXHR.responseText);
            console.log(oData);
            $Container.find('.title').text(oData.Title);
            $Container.find('.plot').text(oData.Plot);
            $Container.find('.poster').html('<img src="' + oData.Poster + '" alt=""/>');
            $Container.find('.year').text(oData.Year);
            $Container.find('.rated').text(oData.Rated);
            $Container.show();
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Could you reduce your code more? It sounds like you're just making a request and not getting back the results you're looking for.

Comment: You should check body of your response. Have you checked the API page with your failed query?

Comment: @TrankorSmash I am getting the results I want, but if I search for a movie that's not found it still shows the details for the previous search results where I would like it to display nothing. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On failed query this API responds as follows:

```
{"Response":"False","Error":"Movie not found!"}
```

with status code `200`, so you should check the body from response.

Edit:

You can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method on response object and check is this object has `title` property, then call `Container.show()`, in other case do nothing or show information about no results in DOM.

Edit 2:

```
oData = $.parseJSON(p_oXHR.responseText);

if (oData.hasOwnProperty("Title")) {
    $Container.find(".title").text(oData.Title);
    $Container.find(".plot").text(oData.Plot);
    $Container.find(".poster").html('<img src="' + oData.Poster + '" alt=""/>');
    $Container.find(".year").text(oData.Year);
    $Container.find(".rated").text(oData.Rated);
} else {
    $Container.find(".error").text(oData.Response);
}
$Container.show();
```

If your container still would be has information about the previous video, probably you should implement method for clearing DOM with I guess [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method or other method from [DOM Removal](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-removal/) section.

Comment: Sorry I'm still totally lost. Ive tried googling it for the last hour or so and tried a few things, but can't seem to make anything work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time, but It's way over my head and I think it's time to admit defeat. Most things like this I can  hack away at and eventually get it to work, but this one's got me.

Comment: Am I on the right track with this? I know there's an error, but if I'm close I'll keep trying. `$Container.find('.year').text(oData.Year);
oData.hasOwnProperty('Title');   // returns true
$Container.show();
oData.hasOwnProperty('False,Error:Movie not found!');   // returns false
alert("I am an alert box!"); 
}`

Comment: Almost good look at Edit 2 and please read `hasOwnProperty` documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is still holding information so I'll have a look at DOM Removal and go through hasOwnProperty again and see if I can make sense of it. You have been very paitent and helpful

Comment: You're welcome! If you want, please consider evaluating my answer. :)

Comment: I got it working with `$( ".title" ).empty();
  $( ".plot" ).empty();` etc thank you